# WHERE clause on a date in a for loop

Tags: apex, soql, scheduled-apex, loop

I'm trying to find the fee which is active on the date of the worked hours. Goal is to schedule this every week to see our revenues.

```
global class RevenueTimeEntry implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        List<timeEntry__c> TimeEntry = new List<timeEntry__c>(
                [SELECT Id, date__c
                 FROM timeEntry__c 
                 WHERE Fee1__c = null
                 LIMIT 10]);

        System.debug(TimeEntry); 

        for(timeEntry__c te : TimeEntry){
            Decimal fee = [ SELECT Fee2__c
                            FROM AssignmentFee__c 
                            //WHERE DateStart__c <= :TimeEntry.date__c
                            LIMIT 1].Fee2__c;

            te.Fee1__c = fee;
        }
        update TimeEntry;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how I can use the where clause in de for loop so the start date of the Fee is smaller (or equal) to the date of the time entry?

Comment: are you looking for `WHERE DateStart__c <= :TimeEntry.date__c` this condition in for loop?

Comment: Refer this link https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices for best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a best practice to avoid soql query inside the for loop.

check below code.

```
global class RevenueTimeEntry implements Schedulable {

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

    List<timeEntry__c> TimeEntry = new List<timeEntry__c>(
            [SELECT Id, date__c
             FROM timeEntry__c 
             WHERE Fee1__c = null
             LIMIT 10]);

    System.debug(TimeEntry);
     List<timeEntry__c> updateTimeEntry = new List<timeEntry__c>(
    List<AssignmentFee__c> assign = [SELECT Fee2__c, DateStart__c FROM AssignmentFee__c ];

   for(AssignmentFee__c a : assign){
        for(timeEntry__c te : TimeEntry)
        {
        if(a.DateStart__c <= te.date__c)
            {
            te.Fee1__c = a.Fee2__c;
            updateTimeEntry.add(te);
            }
        }
    }
    update updateTimeEntry;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the full solution, I had to put in a check for the same assignment. Cause otherwise you'll get an error for 'same Id found in List'

```
global class OmzetTimeEntry implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        List<timeEntry__c> TimeEntry = new List<timeEntry__c>(
            [SELECT Id, date__c, timeSheet__r.Assignment__c
            FROM timeEntry__c 
            WHERE FeeHour__c = null]);

        List<timeEntry__c> updateTimeEntry = new List<timeEntry__c>();
        List<AssignmentFee__c> assign = [SELECT Fee__c, DateStart__c, Assignment__c FROM AssignmentFee__c ];

        for(AssignmentFee__c a : assign){
            for(timeEntry__c te : TimeEntry) {

                if(a.DateStart__c <= te.date__c &&
                    a.Assignment__c == te.timeSheet__r.Assignment__c) {
                    te.FeeHour__c = a.Fee__c;
                updateTimeEntry.add(te);
                }   
            }
        }
        update updateTimeEntry;
    }
}
```